# Is there any workaround for functions having large number of arguments?

Tags: java, function, arguments

There is a function that I call once in a day :

```
new SubmitLogs().mail(IP, date_time_UTC, date_time_IST , pageVisited , userCountry , userRegion , city , userAgent);
```

The function arguments keep on growing. Initially it was like :

```
new SubmitLogs().mail(IP, date_time_UTC, userAgent);
```

and now it has 5 more arguments. It is expected to contain more arguments in a week.Now I do not like this.Maintaining functions with so many arguments doesn't seem to be a good thing to me. Is there any work around for this ? I will never want to send some 50 arguments to a function if it keeps growing. What the call does is email the details in the argument with a short message and a short subject.

Comment: Create a DataObject class for these parameters and pass its object to method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two options really

1. Try and group some of the parameters together into an object. This will encapsulate similar things together. For example you could put userRegion, userCountry and city together into a Location object
2. Alternatively the [Builder](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=2) pattern is good. Josh Bloch's Effective Java has a good chapter on it.

Comment: +1 for the #2. You may want to summarize the pattern with a small example for these of us who does not have Josh's book.

Comment: Just added a link to the chapter :)

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like:

1. an encapsulation problem. Group your arguments together into one or more logical coherent objects
2. a scope problem. *Is your method trying to do too much ?* Or is this instance-type info that you can configure on the containing object.

A friend of mine once said to me.

> If you have 10 arguments to a function, it's usually a sign that
>   you've forgotten another 5

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need more objects to represent groups of related objects.

```
new SubmitLogs().mail(IP, date_time_UTC, date_time_IST , pageVisited , userCountry , userRegion , city , userAgent);
```

Looks like there's a few objects waiting to come out.

```
public class UserLocation { 
    private string userCountry; 
    private string userRegion;
    private string city;
    // ...
}
```

Now you've simplified it a little

```
new SubmitLogs().mail(IP, data_time_UTC, date_time_IST, pageVisited, userLocation, userAgent);
```

I don't know your domain, but it might be that you can find other groups of data to bring these together.

Once you've got your data together, you might find methods start to move naturally over to those classes.  For example, UserLocation might have a method to write that information out to a stream.

Comment: UserLocation is one thing. It could be that arguments don't have a relation at all !

Comment: @grassPro We generally send similar items in a function. If none of the argument has any relation among them , then it is a design issue

Answer (score 0):

Create a value object and pass that value object instead.  If it is a remote call or something, remember to implement Serializable.

```
class MailParams {

    String ip;
    String dateTimeUTC;
    String dateTimeIST;
    // .... and so on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would only have the mandatory parameters required to send the email as arguments to this method and all the optional parameters would be provided through a Map, where the key of this map will be Enum of that has the list of possible optional parameters and their types and value is the value of that property for a given call.

```
new SubmitLogs().mail(sender, receiver, subject, body, ImmutableMap.<SubmitLogMailParams, Object>of(<param1>, <value1>, <param2>, <value2>, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide different implementations of the method - mail() with 3 params, mail() with 10 params, etc, so the best-matched one can be used.